# Retrieve all the keys of an object inside a mongoose document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents. I'm using mongoose and express.
Each document is built with this schema:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    books: { type: Object },
});
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

export default User;
I can have different couples of "key:value" for each document inside the object "books".

For example,
First document:

```
{
    "firstName": "Lucy",
    "lastName": "Red",
    "email": "lucy.red@mail.com",
    "books": {
        "Harry Potter" : "horrible",
        "Hunger Games" : "beautiful"
     }
}
```

Second document:

```
{
    "firstName": "Tom",
    "lastName": "Brown",
    "email": "tom.brown@mail.com",
    "books": {
        "The Great Gatsby" : "beautiful",
        "Frankenstein" : "horrible"
     }
}
```

What I'd like to do is to query the db collection, and get inside an array all the possible keys that can be found inside each "books" objects.

For this example, I want to retrieve:

```
["Harry Potter" , "Hunger Games", "The Great Gatsby", "Frankenstein"];
```

Does it exist a way for doing this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, if you made the `books` object into an array with sub-documents like ```
{ title: "Harry Potter", rating: "horrible" }
``` it would make your queries a lot simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try somthing as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        
         $project: {
            books: { $objectToArray: "$books" }
         }
      
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$books"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            books: { $push: "$books.k"  }
        }
    }
])
```

The result will be as below:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "books" : [
        "Harry Potter",
        "Hunger Games",
        "The Great Gatsby",
        "Frankenstein"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This could be the solution, but if I have duplicated keys this solution push them inside the array. How could I avoid this? I'd like to have my array without duplicated keys.

Comment: Ok, I've solved this issue doing "res.json([...new Set(booksCollection[0].books)]);" inside my get on api